# Xcode 9 builds project but fails to launch simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I've got XCode 9 building my project and i get an alert: 
**"Error returned in reply: Connection Invalid - Software caused connection abort"**

[image]

Comment: close and start did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

Kill the Xcode, kill all the other instances of Xcode and its simulators, relaunch Xcode 9, cmd + shift + k (clean), Delete derived Data, and run.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error in earlier versions of Xcode when I had two version installed at the same time or both simulators were open.

Seems to be some problem while Xcode was trying to establish connection with simulator.

Try again after closing the simulators.

Answer (score -1):

Quit all the other instance of Xcode and its Simulator.Try these steps to resolve this problem :

- Relaunch Xcode
- cmd+shift+K or Go to the Xcode Menu (Product -> Clean)
- Run

This will solve your problem.